# Why is my JavaScript code not successfully uploading my file?

Tags: javascript, jquery, filereader

Ok, so I have this JavaScript code. It uploads a file by using a FileReader object. But whenever I try to upload a MID file that contains a + character in it's bytes, it changes that into a space! I know the error is not in the server side script, because I checked out the data on the client side right after the FileReader read my MID file and it was the same as the uploaded end result. I tried reading the file as text as well, but that also fails to work. Please ignore the code comments, I put them in to try different versions of some code without having to erase previous ones. I am fairly sure the error is somewhere in the upload function.

**NOTE: For some reason, StackOverflow can not display my code properly. Go to this url to get the full HTML code: http://uploadfilez.tommy3244.com/cgi-bin/index.cgi**

I tried a couple of things for a few hours, but some characters (+, but there may be some others) keep getting turned into a space! I can't figure out what the problem is! If I should upload the original and the end result MID files, please tell me. Thanks!

Comment: yes stackoverflow can display your code properly. No one wants to go through your page source. post the relevant part of your code

Comment: I tried. StackOverflow's <code> and <pre> tags would not display half of the code. The part in the middle, where I think my problem is, would not display, and I was pressed for time.

Answer (score 1):

A quick look at the source suggests that you are using the javascript `escape` function when you don't want to be.

Take a look at lines 80-90 in your source code, and then take a look at the docs on `escape` and the problem should be clear:

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_escape.asp

### EDIT: 1/2/13

I looked into this some more, and I think my answer above is not the problem.  I was able to verify using a breakpoint that the argument being passed to your upload function is correct (ie, I tried with a filename containing "+" chars).

I wasn't able to test with breakpoints inside the upload function, since I don't have your u/p.  However, I still believe you'll find the error in the upload function.  Specifically, I would stop trying to construct the query string manually, as you do here:

```
    var data = "";
    //data.append("filename", document.getElementById("filename0").value);
    data += "filename="+escape(document.getElementById("filename0").value);
    //data.append("username", document.getElementById("username").value);
    data += "&username="+escape(document.getElementById("username").value);
    //data.append("password", document.getElementById("password").value);
    data += "&password="+escape(document.getElementById("password").value);
    //data.append("public", document.getElementById("public").value);
    data += "&public="+escape(document.getElementById("public").value);
    //data.append("filebytes", escape(e.target.result));
    data += "&filebytes="+escape(e.target.result);
    //stdlog("Got result! Res: '''"+e.target.result+"'''");
```

Instead, using JSON to construct the data, like so:

```
var data = {};
data.filename = escape(document.getElementById("filename0").value);//fixed coding error
// and so on for the other properties
```

Try that and let me know if it solves your problem.

Comment: Please explain further. I tried replacing all my escape calls to encodeURI calls, but that made the end result much, much worse. I made a Python program to test the end results, but that ended in about 298 byte differences unless I made a error in my program. Please explain further, I mist be getting something else wrong. Thanks!

Comment: Also, the reader.result variable is the value without any spaces. I had it print out before it was escaped. I thought I might be calling the reader.readAsBinaryString when I should not have.

Comment: I'll try to take a closer look tomorrow.

Comment: Ok, I will try to add that when I have the chance

Comment: Sorry, I tried adding that and changing the processData to true, so $.ajax would process the dictionary, but it was unsuccessful. I am thinking it may just be some glitch with FileReader because I am sure that FileReader is the thing going wrong. Should I try reader.readAsArrayBuffer or reader.readAsText? Or is it some glitch with Chrome, which is what I am using?